# Java error: java.io.IOException: Stream closed when trying to import a zip file into Mendix using Java action

Tags: java, zipinputstream, mendix

I am trying to use a Mendix Java action to import a zipped file of xml files however I am getting the following errors from the Java code:

```
java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(Unknown Source)
```

```
public class Zip_Upload extends CustomJavaAction<java.util.List<IMendixObject>>
{
    private IMendixObject __InputZipFile;
    private system.proxies.FileDocument InputZipFile;

    public Zip_Upload(IContext context, IMendixObject InputZipFile)
    {
        super(context);
        this.__InputZipFile = InputZipFile;
    }

    @java.lang.Override
    public java.util.List<IMendixObject> executeAction() throws Exception
    {
        this.InputZipFile = this.__InputZipFile == null ? null : system.proxies.FileDocument.initialize(getContext(), __InputZipFile);

        // BEGIN USER CODE
        
        
        List<IMendixObject> ZipFiles = new ArrayList<IMendixObject>();
        
        InputStream fileInputStream = Core.getFileDocumentContent(getContext(), InputZipFile.getMendixObject());
        
        
        byte[] buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream);
        fileInputStream.close();
        int bufferlength = buffer.length;
        
        /*String filename = "temp.zip";
        File myFile = new File(Core.getConfiguration().getResourcesPath() + File.separator + filename);
        myFile.createNewFile();
        
        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        outStream.write(buffer);
        outStream.close();
        */
        InputStream clonedStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
        
        int clonedlength = clonedStream.available();
        
        Core.getLogger("Zip Import").log(LogLevel.INFO, "Byte Array Length = " + bufferlength);
        Core.getLogger("Zip Import").log(LogLevel.INFO, "Cloned Input Stream Length = " + clonedlength);
        ZipEntry ze;    
        
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(clonedStream);
        int zislength = zis.available();
        Core.getLogger("Zip Import").log(LogLevel.INFO, "Zip Input Stream availability = " + zislength);
        if ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            IMendixObject FD = Core.instantiate(getContext(),flatfileinterfacecustomizations.proxies.ImportExportDocument.getType());
            Core.storeFileDocumentContent(getContext(), FD, zis);
            FD.setValue(getContext(), flatfileinterfacecustomizations.proxies.ImportExportDocument.MemberNames.Name.toString(), ze.getName());
            ZipFiles.add(FD);                       
        }
        
        
        zis.close();
        clonedStream.close();
        return ZipFiles;
        
        
        // END USER CODE
        
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this action
     * @return a string representation of this action
     */
    @java.lang.Override
    public java.lang.String toString()
    {
        return "Zip_Upload";
    }

    // BEGIN EXTRA CODE
    // END EXTRA CODE
}
```

I tried changing the 'while' to 'if' and this worked successfully, however this only allowed me to import 1 file, and I have multiple to import, hence needing the 'while' loop.

Comment: It looks like `storeFileDocumentContent()` is closing its input stream. And you don’t need the `ByteArrayInputStream`. This is just a waste of time and space. Read directly from the input file.

Comment: Thank you! By removing this, it now seems to have worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user207421, unfortunately although this seems to get the Java to work, it does not seem to be committing the files if i take this out. Where in the code would you recommend I put the 'storeFileDocumentContent()' ?

Answer (score -1):

The `zis.available()` method returns the number of bytes available to read from the current entry. So, using if instead of while only processes the first entry in the zip archive.

Can you do the example:

```html
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(clonedStream);
ZipEntry ze;

while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    IMendixObject FD = Core.instantiate(getContext(), flatfileinterfacecustomizations.proxies.ImportExportDocument.getType());
    Core.storeFileDocumentContent(getContext(), FD, zis);
    FD.setValue(getContext(), flatfileinterfacecustomizations.proxies.ImportExportDocument.MemberNames.Name.toString(), ze.getName());
    ZipFiles.add(FD);
    
    zis.closeEntry();
}

zis.close();
clonedStream.close();
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Available to be read without blocking, but the OP isn’t relying on it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply however this did not seem to work. The solution given by user207421 has worked for me. Thank you anyway :)